# How to make a simple family budget calculator

Tags: python

I am making a simple budget calculator and It is a little bit complicated for me as a beginner. I need to add elements to a list through a function and then print an overview of a specific month and a year. It should sum up the money in each category and print it out.

```
budget=[]
def add_element (day,month,year,money,category):
    budget.append(day,month,year,money,category)
    

def overview (month,year):
       
    
    


add_element(15,10,2022,150,"food")
add_element(16,11,2022,250,"food")
add_element(17,11,2022,300,"living")
add_element(18,11,2022,500,"food")
add_element(19,11,2022,150,"household")

print(overview(11,2022))
```

I am expecting this outcome:

`{"food": 750, "household": 150, "living": 300}`

Comment: maybe you could be interested in plain text accounting https://plaintextaccounting.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar with using defaultdict

```py
from collections import defaultdict
budget = []

def add_element(*row):
    budget.append(row)

def overview(month, year):
    summary = defaultdict(int)
    for d, m, y, money, category in budget:
        if m == month and y == year:
            summary[category] += money
    return summary

add_element(15, 10, 2022, 150, "food")
add_element(16, 11, 2022, 250, "food")
add_element(17, 11, 2022, 300, "living")
add_element(18, 11, 2022, 500, "food")
add_element(19, 11, 2022, 150, "household")

print(overview(11, 2022))  # defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {"food": 750, "household": 150, "living": 300})
```

you can anytime convert to dict using `dict(summary)`

Answer (score 1):

The below code should help you with your need.

```
def add_element(day, month, year, money, category):
        budget.append([day, month, year, money, category])
    
def overview(month, year):
        food_total = 0
        household_total = 0
        living_total = 0
        for item in budget:
            if item[1] == month and item[2] == year:
                if item[4] == "food":
                    food_total += item[3]
                elif item[4] == "household":
                    household_total += item[3]
                elif item[4] == "living":
                    living_total += item[3]
        return {"food": food_total, "household": household_total, "living": living_total}
    
budget = []
add_element(15,10,2022,150,"food")
add_element(16,11,2022,250,"food")
add_element(17,11,2022,300,"living")
add_element(18,11,2022,500,"food")
add_element(19,11,2022,150,"household")
print(overview(11,2022))
```

Comment: What if you get any new `item` in `budget`? Not in ["food", "household", "living"]. Looks not really universal.

Comment: I mean new `category`